# How to get real client IP directly from nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I want to get the final real client IP direct from nginx return, and avoid getting the IP of proxy servers.

The articles I have searched are all something like

```
server /client-ip {
    ...
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    ...
}
```

But this format is for applications to get IP from request.

How can it directly return the real client IP when the URL is hit?
like

```
server /client-ip {
    ...
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    return "$X-real-ip"
}
```

But of course, the above format is not working.
How can I modify the above format to get final client's IP directly without getting proxy server's IP?

Answer (score 0):

```
http {
  # …
  server {
    # …
    location /client-ip {
      return 200 $remote_addr;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry I have edited my question, this method will get the proxy servers IP sit between client and application.

Comment: @Aaron you can use this: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html, just replace $remote_addr with $realip_remote_addr and add the relevant real_ip options.